# Can you decipher these ancient numerals?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

This stone was found at the foot of an ancient door.

[image: 1]

This old note with some mathematical relationships was discovered nearby.

[image: 2]

Can you use this information to figure out what number each of the 9 symbols on the stone represent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Overall solution

The nine symbols are, in the arrangement given:

> `9  0  3`
>  `5  1  2`
>  `4  7  8`

### Step-by-step deductions

From the factorial relationship,

> two different digits with one being the factorial of the other must be either $0!=1$ or $3!=6$.

But from the perfect-power relationship,

> two different digits, one raised to the power of the other giving a third single digit, must be $2^3=8$ or $3^2=9$.

So

> 2 and 3 both appear in that perfect-power relationship, which means the factorial relationship is **not** $3!=6$. Therefore the hooked symbol is $0$ and the P-shaped symbol is $1$.

The top left (division) relationship

> is a red herring, making you think the jagged symbol must be 1, when in fact it's the hooked symbol being $0$.

From the square root relationship,

> the X-shaped one is either 4 or 9 (we've already found 1), and the h-shaped one is correspondingly either 3 or 4. Since we already know 3 is in the perfect-power relationship, that means the h-shaped one is $4$ and the X-shaped one is $9$.

Going back to the perfect-power relationship,

> since we now have 9, that weird symbol on the right is $8$, the moose symbol is $2$, and the mushroom symbol is $3$.

Now for the big product relationship:

> the right-hand side is $3(9+1)=30=5\times6$, so the zigzag and the jagged symbol are $5$ and $6$ in some order.

From the division relationship at the bottom,

> the zigzag symbol is $5$ (the smaller one) and the jagged symbol is $6$.

Finally then

> the double-triangle symbol (the only one not appearing in the given relations) must be $7$.

Note that

> the jagged symbol for 6 does not appear on the stone!